# Change datetime format from dash to slash

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very frustrating error. Could you help please.

```
df['timestamp'] = [datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]
df.set_index('timestamp')
```

This gives the following dataframe:

```
timestamp
2020-01-24 03:00:00    0.008018
2020-01-24 04:00:00    0.008856
2020-01-24 05:00:00    0.005884
2020-01-24 06:00:00    0.010449
2020-01-24 07:00:00    0.009826
```

I want to change the format of the datime as follow:

```
df['timestamp'] = datetime.strptime(df['timestamp'], '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But I have the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "poly_regression_test.py", line 99, in <module>
    df['timestamp'] = datetime.strptime(df['timestamp'], '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1064, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py", line 1003, in get_value
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'timestamp'
```

Answer (score 3):

You made `timestamp` an index, so you cannot call it anymore using its label. Try this instead:

```
df['timestamp'] = datetime.strptime(df.index, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do with `pandas`

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index, '%d/%m/%Y').dt.date
```