# Change the format of the date from slash to dash in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

The current format of my date in my dataframe is YYYY/MM/DD.

I would like to change this to dashes in the following format YYYY-MM-DD.

How would this be done in python pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change datetime format from dash to slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61241121/change-datetime-format-from-dash-to-slash)

Comment: Try referring this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `replace` it. Use `format` to format your `date` column. This is more pythonic way of doing it. For millions of rows data, `replace` method is extremely inefficient.

```
# Create a list of data
data = ["2023/03/19", "2023/04/16", "2023/06/21", "2023/09/21", "2023/12/31"]

# Create a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["date"])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = "%Y/%m/%d")
# Print the DataFrame
print(df)

date
0 2023-03-19
1 2023-04-16
2 2023-06-21
3 2023-09-21
4 2023-12-31
```